# Recon-ng on Windows disables all modules

Tags: python, windows-10

I was running Python 3.5 but got to know that recon-ng tool runs on Python 2.8 or below. Therefore I installed Python 2.7.11 also on my Windows 10 system. I installed the dependencies also mentioned in the REQUIREMENTS file that comes with the recon-ng. Everything got installed properly but when I start up recon-ng with the command `python27 recon-ng --no-check`, I am getting the following error:

```
[!] Module 'readline' not available. Tab complete disabled.   
[!] Module 'C:\Users\vishi\recon-ng\modules\discovery\info_disclosure/cache_snoop' disabled. Dependency required: 'me is not supported.'.  
[!] Module 'C:\Users\vishi\recon-ng\modules\discovery\info_disclosure/interesting_files' disabled. Dependency required: 'me is not supported.'.  
[!] Module 'C:\Users\vishi\recon-ng\modules\exploitation\injection/command_injector' disabled. Dependency required: 'me is not supported.'.  
[!] Module 'C:\Users\vishi\recon-ng\modules\exploitation\injection/xpath_bruter' disabled. Dependency required: 'me is not supported.'.  
[!] Module 'C:\Users\vishi\recon-ng\modules\import/csv_file' disabled. Dependency required: 'me is not supported.'.  
[!] Module 'C:\Users\vishi\recon-ng\modules\import/list' disabled. Dependency required: 'me is not supported.'.  
[!] Module 'C:\Users\vishi\recon-ng\modules\recon\companies-contacts/bing_linkedin_cache' disabled. Dependency required: 'me is not supported.'.  
[!] Module 'C:\Users\vishi\recon-ng\modules\recon\companies-contacts/indeed' disabled. Dependency required: 'me is not supported.'.  
[!] Module 'C:\Users\vishi\recon-ng\modules\recon\companies-contacts/linkedin_auth' disabled. Dependency required: 'me is not supported.'.  
[!] Module 'C:\Users\vishi\recon-ng\modules\recon\companies-contacts\jigsaw/point_usage' disabled. Dependency required: 'me is not supported.'.  
[!] Module 'C:\Users\vishi\recon-ng\modules\recon\companies-contacts\jigsaw/purchase_contact' disabled. Dependency required: 'me is not supported.'.  
[!] Module 'C:\Users\vishi\recon-ng\modules\recon\companies-contacts\jigsaw/search_contacts' disabled. Dependency required: 'me is not supported.'.....................................
```

And lot more.

In the end it is showing `87 modules disabled` which is the total number of modules present in it. Although I am still getting the interactive shell at the end and able to execute the "help" command. But, when I am trying to execute "show modules" command, it is expectedly throwing an error. Please suggest how to remediate this.

Comment: this looks like a python question, not a security question (regardless of what you are trying to run in python)

Answer (score 1):

Recon-ng creator here. Recon-ng loads all modules upon startup. If the dependencies are not present, then the modules will fail to load as seen above. In this case, the dependencies are most likely installed, but Recon-ng is not supported in Windows, causing all of the modules to fail to load, and resulting in these errors. Recon-ng is only supported on Linux-based operating systems. You could use a Docker container to run Recon-ng on Windows.